# How do i fix type error

Tags: javascript, react

i an getting an error in my react build online, even though it seems to be working fine locally.

react-dom.production.min.js:189 TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length')
at VK (MyChallengeTab.js:59:23)

The code below is here the error is coming from, anyone with a fix pls?
Pls provide me with an edit to correct for this?

```
<div className="m-4">
        <Pagination
          total={data.length}
          defaultCurrent={page}
          defaultPageSize={perPage}
          showTotal={(total) => `Total ${total} items`}
          onChange={handleMyChange}
        />
      </div>
```

Comment: I'd guess the problem is that `data` is null. Where's that coming from?

Comment: I'm a bit behind on the new block editor: is this a Gutenberg block? Is Pagination provided by WordPress?

Comment: this is react js

Comment: Yes sure, but you've posted this on the WordPress Development and WordPress's Gutenberg blocks use react, so I was asking if this is a Gutenberg block. I guess it isn't then, this has no connection to WordPress?

Comment: None at all. Thank you for bringing it to my notification